# Why would a lua module set its table's __index as itself?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I noticed a lua module setting the returned table's `__index` as itself

```
local M = {
  _VERSION = "1.0.0"
}
M.__index = M

function M.do()
end

return M
```

What does setting a table's `__index` as itself accomplish?

Later, you would use the module

```
local m = require("m")
m.do()
```

Comment: In the code you've provided, it does nothing. `M` is never used as a metatable, so the `__index` field isn't particularly relevant. It's just another key in the table. Can you provide a more complete example?

Comment: It sounds likely that 'it does nothing' is the correct answer.

Comment: It's more likely that you're incorrectly copying something you saw in a module. That's why I want to see a complete example.

Comment: We do need `uroborus` tag!

Comment: It is https://github.com/zmartzone/lua-resty-openidc/blob/master/lib/resty/openidc.lua#L76

Answer (score 3):

It is usually done to avoid creating a separate metatable to be used in objects created by the library:

```
function M.new()
    return setmetatable({},M)
end
```

I do this all the time in my libraries. It is somewhat lazy.